# How do I add a logo on shipping option?

Tags: magento

I cloned tablerate shipping method to have another option (fast courier).
I checked everywhere on how can I add a logo when displaying shipping options.

**What I did**:
in public function `collectRates` inside my shipping model I added

```
$method->setLogo( $this->getShipmentImageSrc('postaromana') );
$result->append($method);
```

So now I have the logo path, the problem is that I don't know how to call it. I supose the call is made in

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

**Any ideas how to solve this?**

Comment: You should provide your solution as an answer and not inside your question. Then accept it as the correct answer (even though it's your own). You will be able to accept it after a predefined period of time (I think in two days)

Comment: next time, don't ask your question in your answer, add an answer and mark that as the correct answer, so everyone that is looking for can easily find it.

Comment: thanks for the tip. Sorry about that. I'll keep in mind in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution for my question.

I share my solution in case anyone need it.

In `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/etc/system.xml` add this on your new carrier

```
<logo>
    <label>Logo</label>
    <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
    <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_image</backend_model>
    <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="0">freeshippingtimisoara/logo</upload_dir>
    <base_url type="media" scoope_info="0">freeshippingtimisoara/logo</base_url>
    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</logo>
```

Add this function on carrier model from `/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier`

```
public function getShipmentImageSrc($shipping)
{
    $logo = $this->getConfigData('logo');
    $imageFilepath = DS . $shipping . DS . $_code . 'logo' . DS . $logo;
    if( file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').$imageFilepath) ){
        return Mage::getBaseUrl('media').$imageFilepath;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Clone `/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method/Available.php` to local and add this function:

```
public function getCarrierLogo($carrierCode)
{
    if ($logo = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/logo')) 
    {
        $carrierModel = Mage::getModel('shipping/carrier_' . $carrierCode);
        $logo = $carrierModel->getShipmentImageSrc($carrierCode);
        return $logo;
    }
    //$shippingModel = Mage::getModel('shipping/shipping');
    //$carrier = $shippingModel->getShipmentImageSrc($carrierCode);
    //Mage::helper('firephp')->debug( $carrier );
}
```

Use this in `app/design/frontend/default/sex/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`
I have this file in my template, it's best to copy it to your template if you want to alter.

```
<?php if($this->getCarrierLogo($code)): ?>
    <span class="carrier-desc" style="margin:0 10px">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getCarrierLogo($code) ?>" alt="<?php echo $_code; ?>" />
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: remember to make this answer the correct answer, click the ok icon below the up/down vote icons.